# como referenciar css externo em uma pagina HTML

Tags: html, css

estou aprendendo html mas nao sei por que nao tou conseguindo chama um arquivo css, que criei separado para meu html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> aula 5 </title>
        <link rel="styleshet" type="css" href="atyle9.css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Este é um paragrafo com elemento <em>EM </em> nele </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O corpo que faz referencia para o CSS esta incompleto.
Dentro do href nao seria "style9.css" ao invez de "atyle9.css" ?
tente colocar desta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="atyle9.css"/>
```

Comment: muito obrigado funcicou XD, estou inicando esse negocio é meio complicado.

Comment: Disponha sempre. Se resolveu o seu problema não esquece de marca como resposta correta.

Answer (score 1):

Não se utiliza `type="css"` e sim `type="text/css"` verifica também se o caminho e nome do arquivo estão corretos.

Comment: O caminho estava incorreto tambem..